# PHP -> ezcomponents -> graph -> palette -> colors don't change

Tags: graph, palette, zeta-components

we are drawing graphs with ezcomponents graph classes in PHP within a Zend Framework application. Now I have to customize a StackBar chart. Following the tutorials you can set custom colors to the graphs' elements by creating a palette class and set some properties. Here we go:

```
class My_Graph_Palettes_Shc extends ezcGraphPalette
{
    protected $dataSetColor = array('#FF4E9A', '#3465A4', '#F57900');
    protected $dataSetSymbol = array(
            ezcGraph::BULLET,
    );
    protected $fontName = 'sans-serif';
    protected $fontColor = '#000000'; 
    protected $axisColor = '#000000';
    protected $majorGridColor = '#bbbbbb';
 }
```

We can set axisColor or majorGridColor using this class but the color of the chart elments cannot be set with the dataSetColor property as documented. It simply doesnt change anything.

Do you know what we are missing? Pls let us know if so.

Cheers, J

Answer (score 0):

The palette has to be set before $graph->data[$keys] are set, at least in our case. Then it works fine.